# I have a SQL view with a UNION, and when used via Entity Framework the results are wrong. Why?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

So my ASP.NET MVC4 app uses EF. For my specific situation, I chose to implement part of the logic in a SQL view, and the rest of it in EF. This is an approach that we have successfully used before: using EF as much as possible, but using TSQL in views for logic that seems easier in TSQL than in EF. Here is my TSQL view:

```
SELECT P.DeviceID, P.PhoneNumber, E.FullName, Effective  
FROM PhoneNumbers P 
    INNER JOIN Devices D ON D .DeviceID = P.DeviceID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vEmployees E ON P.AssignedEmployeeNumber = E.EmployeeID
UNION
SELECT H.DeviceID, H.PhoneNumber, E.FullName, MIN(Effective) AS Effective
FROM PhoneNumberHistory H 
    INNER JOIN Devices D ON D .DeviceID = H.DeviceID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vEmployees E ON H.AssignedEmployeeNumber = E.EmployeeID
GROUP BY H.DeviceID, H.PhoneNumber, E.FullName
```

And there isn't much going on in my Service code calling EF:

```
return this.deviceHistoryRepository.GetMany(d => d.DeviceID == id)
           .OrderByDescending(d => d.Effective).ToList();
```

Naively, I would expect the same data to be returned when running the view directly from SQL (with a WHERE clause of course, to specify the DeviceID), and via the call to EF. But instead, the results from EF have missing rows and duplicate rows. Is there something I'm missing? Something else I can add to my TSQL in my view so that EF can use it correctly?

Comment: Although I've answered my own question, I would welcome better answers. Either a cleaner solution, or a deeper explanation of the solution I have. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it turns out there is (something I can add to my SQL in my view so that EF can use it correctly). EF needs a unique, non-nullable key to properly work with the results of the view.

```
SELECT ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)), -1) AS DeviceHistoryID, *
FROM (
    -- original TSQL from above --
) AS XYZ
```

Since I'm using EF for sorting and manipulating the view's results, I don't care about the order in the view. But the OVER clause requires an ORDER BY, so "SELECT 0". Why am I aliasing the subquery as XYZ? TSQL chokes with a syntax error if there is no alias, even though the alias is not used. And the ISNULL signals EF that this column should be marked as an Entity Key. (Without it marked as such, results returned may not be correct.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the compelling reason to have to dance through hoops like this?  Why don't you simply access the view using .Net SqlClient?

Comment: Because EF works great the vast majority of the time, and saves a lot of coding effort. It's only corner cases like this that get messy, and they are only messy the first time they are encountered. The "hoop" is three lines of boilerplate TSQL. The "fallback position" would probably be to use EF with a stored procedure, instead of abandoning EF for SqlClient.